# Fluent NHibernate mapping with HasMany which fails to return child collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

So I created a new simple project just to help a friend.
So I made a class Customer which has a list of Stuff

So far so good, now with the mapping and storing the relationsship. I went to map in accordance with fluent nhibernate class maps and ended up with the following

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer> {
    Id(p => p.Id).GenerateBy.Guid();
    HasMany(p => p.Stuff).Access.CamelCaseField().KeyColumn("Id").Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
}

public class StuffMap : ClassMap<Stuff> {
   Id(p => p.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
   Reference(p => p.Customer).Column("CustomerId).Not.Nullable();
}
```

and my classes

```
public class Customer {
   private ISet<Stuff> stuff = new HashSet<Stuff>()
   public virtual IEnumerable<Stuff> Stuff => stuff;
   public void AddStuff(Stuff newstuff) {
      newstuff.Customer = this;
      stuff.Add(stuff);
   }
}

public class Stuff {
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

All this works good and when I create a new Customer and add one of more Stuff elements into the collection using the method AddStuff and commits the transaction it gets correctly written to the database.

However now the strange begins, when I make a test like the following

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestStuffAndCustomer() {
   var customer = session.Add(new Customer());
   customer.AddStuff(new Stuff());
   session.Flush();

   var customer = session.Query<Customer>().Single();
   customer.Stuff.Should().HaveCount(1);
}
```

The assertion of the collection fails with reason that the count of the collection is 0. However if I debug the test and check the collection it contains one element. The assertion fails regardless however.

So what is wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I think you add new Customer and Stuff to Customer on session, but without saving them you flush the session.

Comment: I have tried both to commit the session and open a new for the assertion instead of just flushing. Neighter seem to work, or it works as both elements gets saved but I can't seem to check the number of Stuffs in the assertion.

Comment: You can change .Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan(); to .Inverse().Cascade.SaveOrUpdate() then.

Comment: Tried that it doesn't change it at all. Its strange that I can check the fetched Customer in debugmode and see that the Stuff list contains one element but the assertion then fails.